# PhoneGap Debug - concept

Tags: cordova

There are some difference in how the device will behave and some mobiles had features others dont have so what is the best way to debug and test PhoneGap applications on different platforms without the need to purchase expensive mobile devices ?

This is just a concept question. Please list all possible tools or methods with links to resources

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few links,hopfully it will work.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494768/Debugging%20PhoneGap%20Apps

http://phonegap.com/2011/05/18/debugging-phonegap-javascript/

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html

http://www.frenchguys.com/wordpress/showing-console-consolelog-output-phonegap-androideclipse/

Comment: but it seems I must get an expensive iPad !!